# Посчитать количество значений в столбце датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Как посчитать кол-во пациентов с диабетом и без? Диагноз(диабет); да = 1, нет = 0

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with lenght {lenght} bytes'.format(name=fn, lenght=len(uploaded[fn])))
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
data = pd.read_excel(r"1.diabetes1.xls")
print(data.head())
print(data[-1:])
print("Средний возраст: " + str(data['Возраст'].mean()))
#print("Все с диагнозом: " + str(data['Диагноз'].sum()))

a = data['Диагноз']
a
```

[image: Таблица, пять первых значений и последнее]

[image: Столбец с диагнозом]

Comment: В следующий раз - воспроизводимый пример исходных данных (в текстовом виде) должен быть в вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть метод `.value_counts()`, который показывает, какие есть значения в колонке и какое есть количество каждого из этих значений.

```
data['Диагноз'].value_counts()
```